# Accessing model methods from outside without creating an object

Tags: ruby

I have the following method:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  def my_func(str)
    puts str
  end
end
```

I can't seem to call it from outside the class like this:

```
Store::my_func("hi")
```

Any idea why?

Comment: This works only for instances: `Store.new.my_func("hi")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have defined is an *instance method*.  Basically this means you can only call it on *instances* of that class.

```
store = Store.new
store.my_func("hi")
```

If you want a *class method*, you need to define it a little differently.  Either:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.my_func(str)
    puts str
  end
end
```

Or (more useful if you're defining a lot of class methods):

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def my_func(str)
      puts str
    end
  end
end
```

The above two work because classes are also instances of the class `Class`, so the implicit receiver `self` in the above two examples is that instance (the class itself).

You call a class method like this:

```
Store.my_func("hi")
```